# Exist any drawback if i use a callback function inside of a thread to comunicate with the main thread of my app?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

i wrote a Thread.descendent class, and to comunicate my thread with the main thread i use a callback function so i am wondering if is a valid solution or instead i must use windows messages?

```
type
   TMyCallBack= procedure(const Param1,Param2: string) of object;
   TMyThread= class(TThread)
   private
    P1 : string;
    P2 : string;
    MyCallBack    : TMyCallBack;
     procedure Process;
   public
     Constructor Create(CallBack : TMyCallBack); overload;
     destructor Destroy; override;
     procedure Execute; override;
   end;

procedure TMyThread.Process;
begin
  FCallBack(P1,P2);    
end;


constructor TMyThread.Create(CallBack : TMyCallBack);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  MyCallBack    := CallBack;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
    while True and not Terminated do
    begin
     AResult:= FListener.GetResult(Param1,Param2,5000);
      if not VarIsNull(AResult) then
      begin
        P1:=AResult.Value1;
        P2:=AResult.Value2;
        Synchronize(Process);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: You're calling the callback inside a _Synchronized_ method, thus in fact this is running inside the main thread.  The possible drawback of this is your thread have to wait until the main thread process this method, if it is OK to your application, it is OK. Other thing is in fact, by using Synchronize, you're using windows messages.

Comment: Do you even need the thread? What exactly is FListener doing? Can you run it out of your main thread's message pump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you use Synchronize you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the callback via `Synchronize`, it's OK, as most Delphi implementations:

- create a callback structure, containing the callback and an event handle
- append the callback structure to a locked global list
- post a message to the main thread, to wake it from `WaitMessage` or alike
- wait on the event until the callback completes

This may or may not be better than using raw window messages, as:

- the callback list is checked in clearly defined places and as such its not *as much* eligible for reentrancy issues
- for the same reasons, its certainly a bit less performant
- it may cause problems with modal windows and native popup menus, which allow sent message processing, but may bypass the synchronization list handling in some cases

As long as the callback processing must mot be waitable/cancellable, and you can tell *for sure* it doesn't do *anything* that might cause sent message processing (as most windows-message-related routines do!), you may prefer using `SendMessage`, with appropriate parameter marshaling.

Comment: No need to marshal parameters for an in-process `SendMessage`.

Comment: By "parameter marshalling", I mean the possible wrapping of thread-instance pointer, the callback pointers and possibly other data into a structure, as you only have two pointer-size parameters for use and you may need to pass more data with the message send.

Comment: Marshalling is normally used to describe the process of getting buffers from one address space to another, e.g. that done when you send `WM_SETTEXT` or `WM_COPYDATA`.